# How do I group datetimes with a sqlite windowing function?

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite

Let's say I have a table with the following fields:

customerid, transactiontime, transactiontype

I want to group a customer's transactions by time, and select the customerid and the count of those transactions. But rather than simply grouping all transaction times into certain increments (15 min, 30 min, etc.), for which I've seen various solutions here, I'd like to group a set a customer's transactions based on how soon each transaction occurs after the previous.

In other words, if any transaction occurs more than 15 minutes after a previous transaction, I'd like it to be grouped separately.

I expect the customer to generate a few transactions close together, and potentially generate a few more later in the day. So if those two sets of transactions occur more than 15, 30 minutes apart, they'll be grouped into separate windows. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do this using a window function in SQLite. This syntax is a bit new to me, but this is how it would start:

```
select   customer_id, 
         event_start_minute,
         sum(subgroup_start) over (order by customer_id, event_start_minute) as subgroup
from     (
              select customer_id,
                     event_start_minute,
                     case
                       when  event_start_minute  - lag(event_start_minute) over win > 15
                        then 1
                        else 0
                        end as subgroup_start
               from t1
               window win as (
                                          partition by b
                                          order by c
                                        )
         ) as groups
order by customer_id,  event_start_minute
```